# Bulletin board software with voting capability for each post

Tags: website-features, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Forum Software should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25771/what-forum-software-should-i-use)

I run my system on a linux machine. Let's say I use apache or cherokee webserver, for simplicity. I want to run a bulletin board software for discussion purposes. However I do not want traditional systems like vBulletin or vanilla, as systems based on these tend towards too much bickering and clique-formation.

I was inspired by the system in meta.stackoverflow in which each post can be voted up or down. This would instantly be a medicine for all the jerks, since their posts will get downvoted quickly. Moreover honest criticisms will get upvoted. So I feel this will be a great improvement. However the meta.stackoverflow system is not suitable for a discussion environment. I would want a traditional bulletin board system itself; but with the added capability that votes can be given up/down for each post, and for each post the number of votes is displayed.

For example let me mention that in some wordpress blogs, comments can be voted up/down. That capability is exactly what I want; it is just that I need it in a bulletin board software rather than in a wordpress blog.

Question:

> Does there exist a bulletin board software with voting capability for each post?

Here I must stress that I do not care about the total reputation of a user. That is something I do not want to encourage.

I have asked this question both here and at serverfault, since it was not clear where should this be asked. Feel free to close it at the appropriate site and I need answers only from one place.

Answer (score 2):

There are plugins for popular forum software that add voting capabilities. I know that this exists for vBulletin and I'm sure there are versions for phpBB and SMF.

Though you ought to look at what you need this for - I mean, does the voting actually do anything? On the Stack Exchange platform, for example, the highest-voted answers bubble to the top. You can't do that in a regular forum setting because the posts are linear.

Answer (score 1):

Anweshi, give MyBB (http://www.mybb.com/features/reputation) a try.  It seems to be a pretty close approximation of what you're looking for and has a very nice UI to boot.

Comment: Is it possible to configure this to not to display the total reputation, but only the individual post ratings?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure...I've only used it as a participant.  But as most php systems go, they're fairly easy to modify if you're so inclined.

Honestly, what you're looking to do isn't too difficult....a strong developer could probably have it worked through from scratch in two week's time.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Vanilla Forums](http://vanillaforums.org/) with the [Voting plugin](http://vanillaforums.org/addon/voting-plugin). A demo can be seen [here](http://vanillaforums.org/discussions). Vanilla is an acquired taste. :-)