# Forums/CMS/BBS that actually has a bulletin board look

Tags: cms, forum

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Forum Software should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25771/what-forum-software-should-i-use)

Hi I'm wanting to build a bulletin board system for my community which can create a view that actually looks like a "real-world" bulletin board or cork-board. So in addition to the traditional forum view which has a hierarchy of topics in a full-width screen, a page custom to the user could be presented where selected posts could be laid out. The posts might look like sticky notes or boxes, laid out around the page potentially with images and text, rather than being full-screen width text entries.

I'd also like the system to be able to mail a version or screenshot of the custom user page to the user on a weekly basis.

Does anybody know of any, highly preferably open-source, solutions that come with a feature like this?

Comment: so i'm probaby looking like something which looks look more like pinboard than standard threaded forums

Answer (score 1):

http://vanillaforums.org/ has a plugin architecture, you may be able to extend this to meet your needs.

Comment: i might accept the answer if you could specify a plugin which answers the question

Comment: @Nicholas I doubt such an animal exists, hence the suggestion, unlike most forums mentioned in your question vanilla has a decent plugin architecture and a big developer community. The rest is up to you.