# Which free PHP based forum is the easiest to extend or customize?

Tags: forum, free, open-source

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Forum Software should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25771/what-forum-software-should-i-use)

I am looking to start a new forum, with a traditional forum layout (like webhostingtalk, for example).

In this space, I know phpBB and SMF are strong contenders. I do not know for sure the names of other great forum software that might exist...

My most important need is that it should be easy to modify the display area, at the least, without having to dig too much into the core. Drupal excels in this area with its templating system, but the forum module doesn't look like the forum interface most people are used to...

It would be a great plus if the software has alternative Captchas like question based or invisible Captcha. If it doesn't, I would like to be able to code it in without much trouble (that is, the software exposes a good API)

Comment: The suggested duplicate is about CMS, but this question is specifically about forum software...?

Comment: Personally I've found http://vanillaforums.org/ to be the most useful/extensible.

Comment: w3d - I asked about a forum software, but this question was closed as a duplicate of the catch-all CMS question. I feel this is overzealous moderation, and I'm going to open a meta question about this closure.

Comment: Thanks for answering, @toomanyairmiles, indeed Vanilla is very good code-wise. But I want the old-school forum look, like I the example site I specified in the question, and it is not feasible to bend vanilla into becoming that...

Comment: @adityamenon there are a number of themes available including classic style ones http://vanillaforums.org/addon/browse/themes

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @toomanyairmiles, I'll give it a final look before deciding between Vanilla and SMF.

Comment: +1 for Vanilla. Not perfect, that's for sure, but easy to understand and extend.

Comment: If anyone is curious, here's the meta I mentioned: http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/753/14445